# Efficiently query on first two digits of indexed int column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table (MySQL 8.0.26, InnoDB) containing an indexed column of `MEDIUMINT`s that denote the date a record was created:

```
date_created MEDIUMINT NOT NULL
INDEX idx_created (date_created)
```

E.g., the entry "210516" denotes 2021-05-16.

Are the following queries roughly equally efficient in utilizing the index?

`WHERE 210000<=date_created AND date_created<220000`,

`WHERE date_created DIV 10000 = 21`,

`WHERE date_created LIKE '21%'`, and

`WHERE LEFT(date_created, 2) = '21'`

I am currently using `WHERE date_created DIV 10000 = 21` in my code but wonder if I should alter all queries to make them more efficient.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why is the `date_created` field a `MEDIUMINT` and not something like `DATE` (or `DATETIME`)?

Comment: Good question.  I inherited this table and have not really thought about revamping it completely.  I agree that this should have been a `DATE` column to begin with.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see how the different queries are executed. I suspect only the first version will use the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `type` column in EXPLAIN. If it says "ALL" it means it must do a table-scan of all the rows, evaluating the condition expression for each row. This is not using the index.

```
mysql> explain select * from mytable where 21000<=date_created and date_created < 22000;
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | NULL       | range | date_created  | date_created | 4       | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+

mysql> explain select * from mytable where date_created like '21%';
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | NULL       | ALL  | date_created  | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 8192 |    11.11 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+

mysql> explain select * from mytable where date_created div 10000 = 21;
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 8192 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+

mysql> explain select * from mytable where left(date_created, 2) = '21';
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 8192 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

MySQL 8.0 supports expression indexes, which helps a couple of the cases:

```
mysql> alter table mytable add index expr1 ((left(date_created, 2)));

mysql> explain select * from mytable where left(date_created, 2) = '21';
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | NULL       | ref  | expr1         | expr1 | 11      | const | 1402 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+

mysql> alter table mytable add index expr2 ((date_created DIV 10000));

mysql> explain select * from mytable where date_created div 10000 = 21;
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | NULL       | ref  | expr2         | expr2 | 5       | const | 1402 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
```

But expression indexes won't help the `LIKE '21%'` search, because you'd have to hard-code the value `'21%'` in the expression for the index definition. You could use that index to search for that value only, not for the value of a different year.